# Weblogic 12.2 - CXF 3.1 - JAXB 2.2 - Deployment : Error javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix X is not bound

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, cxf, weblogic12c

Error occurs when starting weblogic server:

Problem with the wsdl generated:

```js
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix X is not bound.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix X is not bound.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:375)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The prefix X is not bound.
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.getRefQName(SchemaBuilder.java:823)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.getRefQName(SchemaBuilder.java:831)
```

Namespace not found on the element root while it's defined in the @XmlRootElement

Here the SchemaBuilder.getRefQName source code :

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-xmlschema/blob/master/xmlschema/src/main/java/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/SchemaBuilder.java

```
        prefix = pName.substring(0, offset);
        uri = NodeNamespaceContext.getNamespaceURI(pNode, prefix);
        if (uri == null || Constants.NULL_NS_URI.equals(uri)) {
            if (schema.parent != null
                    && schema.parent.getNamespaceContext() != null) {
                uri = schema.parent.getNamespaceContext().getNamespaceURI(
                        prefix);
            }
        }

        if (uri == null || Constants.NULL_NS_URI.equals(uri)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The prefix " + prefix
                    + " is not bound.");
        }
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution which seems to be better to avoid version compatibility problems is to force your project to use weblogic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved by adding the namesapce in the @XmlType annotation defined in the java entity:

@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "elt1", "elt2", "elt3" }, **namespace ="http://x.y.z"**)